# torrent remote wont connect while on same network

Tags: networking, bittorrent, utorrent

My problem is that my torrent remote app connects fine while I use my phones data connection but fails when I'm at home using WiFi.

I've verified this this problem in the browser as well to make sure the issue wasn't with the torrnent app I'm running (TorrentFu).

My router is running ddwrt, does anyone know of settings I can tweak to get it running properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using DNSMasq following this tutorial:

[Setup Local/Internal DNS with a DD-WRT Router](http://cybernetnews.com/local-internal-dns-ddwrt/)